# Show that $|d(m,n) -d(n,o) | \leq d(m,o)$ for a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Problem

> Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Show that $$|d(m,n) - d(n,o)| \leq d(m,o) \ \forall m,n,o \in M$$

Since $(M,d)$ is a metric space I know it fufills the triangle inequality.

So if I start from $$d(m,n) \leq d(m,o) + d(n,o) \Leftrightarrow \\ d(m,n) - d(n,o) \leq d(m,o)$$ Now if I could prove that $$ d(m,n) - d(n,o) \geq 0  \\ \text{which would give a helpfull result} \ \Rightarrow d(m,n)-d(n,o) = |d(m,n)-d(n,o)|.$$ Can I do that, any hint?

Comment: think of symmetry ! :-)

Comment: Symmetry in $d(m,n) - d(n,o)$?

Comment: the role of $m$ and $o$ is symmetric.

Comment: Yes, but cant see it...

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: The triangle inequality remains true when you replace the three letters $m,n,o$ by any other three letters in order. For example, replace $m,n,o$ by $x,y,z$, or by $u,r,l$, or..... by $o,n,m$, which is what was suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I made a mistake the first time. Here's the correct proof.

> If $d(m,n)=d(n,o)$, then the claim holds. Assume without loss of generality that $d(m,n)> d(n,o)$. Then $d(m,n)\leq d(m,o) + d(o,n)$ (by the triangle inequality) and $d(m,n) - d(o,n) \leq d(m,o)$. Since $d(m,n) > d(o,n)$, $|d(m,n) - d(o,n)|=d(m,n) - d(o,n)$. This gives $|d(m,n) - d(o,n)| \leq d(m,o)$, as desired.

Comment: $ d(x,y) + d(y,z) \geq d(x,z)$ my book says, you have $\leq$

Comment: @Olba12 You are right. I wasn't being careful. I went ahead and corrected it. You basically had it. It is just a matter of breaking it into cases: $d(m,n) > d(n,o)$; $d(m,n) = d(n,o)$; or $d(m,n) < d(n,o)$.